# xamarin c# deserialize Json containing nested object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, xamarin.android

I have a webservice that return a Json in this format :

```
[{
    "Route0": {
        "RouteID": "AAA",
        "RouteDescription": "",
        "ReturnCode": "0",
        "ReturnError": ""
    }
}, {
    "Route1": {
        "RouteID": "AABCLO",
        "RouteDescription": "Antoine Abdo Bachaalani Close",
        "ReturnCode": "0",
        "ReturnError": ""
    }
}]
```

I need to deserialize it:
I created 2 class:

```
public class PullRouteDetailsObjectChild
    {
        public string RouteID { get; set; }
        public string RouteDescription { get; set; }
        public string ReturnCode { get; set; }
        public string ReturnError { get; set; }
    }

    public class PullRouteDetailsObject
    {
        public PullRouteDetailsObjectChild Route { get; set; }
    }
```

and I am using this code to deserialize:

```
    List<PullRouteDetailsObject> jsonRoutes =      
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PullRouteDetailsObject>>(jsonresult);
```

I am able to get a list of 2 PullRouteDetailsObject wich is correct but the child object is always null.
I am sure that I am missing something but can't find what. I need to access child object
 Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this instead:

```
var jsonRoutes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, PullRouteDetailsObject>>>(jsonresult);
```

As you're getting a list of objects with a *property* which contains your 'PullRouteDetailsObject' (Route0, Route1).

Comment: @chahid `jsonRoutes.First(r => r.ContainsKey("Route1"))["Route1"]` (for what it's worth, I don't think the structure of that json helps anybody, client or server)